# My Node.js app seems to also get a delivery pipeline app?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm running a node.js app on bluemix dedicated. What is odd is that it seems to create a new app called "Delivery Pipeline". They both appear as node.js apps in my dashboard and they both appear to share the same actual delivery pipeline.

What is also odd is that the "delivery pipeline" app appears to be the one that actually is running and owns the route.

Just seems really odd to me...

Comment: Do you have a question you would like to ask? What is your Node.js app? How are you deploying it?

Comment: I am deploying using tool chain and git. My question is why is it creating an app called "Delivery Pipeline"?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to check the delivery Pipeline of your toolchain.

[image]

Within the Delivery Pipeline of your toolchain you can define the target application. In your case you might have 2 Delivery Pipelines or you just defined the wrong application name.

[image]